# Error: "Incomplete microdata with schema.org" (Review)

Tags: microdata, schema.org

I'm getting the error when I try to post Review Microdata for a product. I'm wondering what properties are required I have tried several different ways of arrange the data.

This is what Google gives me:

> Item 
>   type: review 
>   property: 
>   name: Some reviewer 
>   author: 
>   Item 1 
>   reviewrating: 
>   Item 2 
>   reviewbody: "The body" 
>   Error: Incomplete microdata with schema.org.
>   Item 1 
>   type: person 
>   property: 
>   name: some Person 
>   Item 2 
>   type: rating 
>   property: 
>   worstrating:  1 
>   bestrating:   5 
>   ratingvalue:  5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just got this to work because of an answer I found posted [here.](http://udinra.com/blog/incomplete-microdata-with-schema-org-review-tag-solution)

I noticed you have name: some reviewer, but the name is supposed to represent the item being reviewed.

For me the solution was to change this name property from itemprop="name" to itemprop="about", and that is what the solution suggests.

I would compare what you have to her working solution for the rest of the property names too, in case it still doesn't work for you. I actually came here first to your question looking for a solution, and then found the solution about 5 minutes later. Hope it works!

Comment: Would like to give you a thumbs up, but I don't have a strong enough rating. This answer was correct and worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Can you accept it as the answer? I am glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

Amurrell has a great suggestion.  Another way would be to include a "thing" schema, such as this:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
<a itemprop="url" href="URL OF PRODUCT OR ITEM"><div itemprop="name"><strong>NAME/TITLE OF THE REVIEW</strong></div>
</a>
<div itemprop="description">DESCRIPTION OF THE ITEM</div>
<div itemprop="reviewBody">REVIEW BODY</div>
<div itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
Written by: <span itemprop="name">NAME OF REVIEWER</span></div>
<div itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing">
<span itemprop="name">ITEM REVIEWED</span></div>
<div><meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2013-10-08">Date published: 10/08/2013</div>
<div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
<meta itemprop="worstRating" content="RATING SCALE MINIMUM, USUALLY 1"><span itemprop="ratingValue">RATING VALUE</span> / <span itemprop="bestRating">RATING SCALE MAXIMUM, USUALLY 5</span> stars</div>
</div>
```

You could also replace the "thing" schema with the "product" schema.  Either would work.

Just replace what I typed in all caps with the actual content of the review.  Hope that helps.